# How to get the value in element child when click a div outside element parent JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, children, getvalue

Sorry my english bad, for example I have 2 columns, every column when click `div.open-model` will show a model have a value is `h3.title`, I used jQuery but i cannot get value `h3.title` every column

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open_modal').click(function(e) {
    var h3title = $(this).find('.parent .title').html();
    console.log('h3title');
    e.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <h3 class="title">Title1</h3>
</div>
<div class="open-model">Open model</div>

<div class="parent">
  <h3 class="title">Title2</h3>
</div>
<div class="open-model">Open model</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `prev()`.

```
var h3title = $(this).prev('.parent').find(".title").text();
```

And after fixing other errors

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open-model').click(function(e) {
    var h3title = $(this).prev('.parent').find(".title").text();
    console.log(h3title);
    e.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the mis-matching class/selector and the use of `'h3title'` as a string

Comment: @Lucas No problem. Mark it answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 1):

You've got several issues here:

- The class on the element is `open-model` so your selector of `open_modal` is incorrect
- `find()` looks for child elements, yet the target you want to find is a child of a sibling, so you need `prev().find()` instead
- `h3title` is a variable, so you don't need to wrap it in quotes when passing it as an argument to `console.log()`.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open-model').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var h3title = $(this).prev('.parent').find('.title').text();
    console.log(h3title);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <h3 class="title">Title1</h3>
</div>
<div class="open-model">Open model</div>

<div class="parent">
  <h3 class="title">Title2</h3>
</div>
<div class="open-model">Open model</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. spelling of selector is wrong on click
2. use `.prev()` instead of `.find()`

   ```js
   $('.open-model').click(function(e) {// fix selector
     var h3title = $(this).prev('.parent').find('.title').html();//use prev()
     console.log(h3title);

   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="parent">
     <h3 class="title">Title1</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="open-model">Open model</div>

   <div class="parent">
     <h3 class="title">Title2</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="open-model">Open model</div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.open-modal').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var h3title = $(this).prev().find('.title').text();
          console.log('h3title');
       });
    });
```

Comment: Could you explain why the OP should do this? Don't forget we're here to educate, so if you explain the problem and why your solution helps then you help the OP expand their knowledge for the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below we are getting the the previous DOM element and as we can see in the structure we want to get the inner text of its child element.

```js
$('.open-model').on('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).prev().children().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <h3 class="title">Title1</h3>
</div>
<div class="open-model">Open model</div>

<div class="parent">
    <h3 class="title">Title2</h3>
</div>
<div class="open-model">Open model</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why the OP should do this? Don't forget we're here to educate, so if you explain the problem and why your solution helps then you help the OP expand their knowledge for the future.